# Laravel: Load different Blade views from Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, laravel-blade

[image: Top Nav with Tabs]

I would like to load a different URL into my Laravel View when I press a Nav Tab.  There is currently three tabs Home, Profile, Messages

This is my JS

```
<script>
    $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url,function(result){      
        pane.tab('show');
    });
});

// load first tab content
$('#home').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"),function(result){
  $('.active a').tab('show');
});
</script>
```

I'm using Bootstrap to style my app

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-url="/custom.html">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-url="/embed/62807/view">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">@include('Partials.FilterBar', array('action' => Str::slug(head(Request::segments()))))</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">sdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
```

Currently when I press Profile it should load /custom.html, but nothing gets loaded.  When I press Messages it should load sdfsdfsdfsdf, but nothing gets loaded.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It gets loaded fine for me. Double check your DOM is fully loaded before u make calls on it. The profile tab doesnt get "loaded" in because i obviously my ajax request gets 404, but messages tab loads fine.   fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/10/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the jsfiddle, but thats the code I have running at the moment on my site http://seek.estate/sold and in Chrome Developer tools there are no errors, but the tabs won't load, not sure why?

Comment: Are you loading the tabs dynamically in javascript ? Like, is this: <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs"> loaded dynamically or is it in your base html file ?

Comment: Ok, when I render your page your script is ABOVE your tabs in the source code.  So what happens is when script executes, tabs are not on the page yet.  In this situation your script can not attach events to your tabs because they dont exist yet.  Move your script to the bottom.

Comment: When I move it to the bottom i get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined seek.estate/sold:94

Comment: ok i got it to work by following what you said thanks